# Why picker behaves differently?

Tags: android, picker

I have designed pickers(number and time picker) in my app. Its working fine but behaves differently in different app. For one it is scrollable but for another it has + and - buttons, which has to be clicked in order to change the value. I want both to be scrolling.

Both the application has min-version 16 and max-version 20. Can anyone guide me to find what can cause this change?

Comment: What theme's do you use in the applications?

Comment: scrollable picker has :                                                                          <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>

Comment: clickable has : <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseThe     <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_indicator</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/app_bg_color</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/cancel</item>
</style>

Comment: And in both the apps AppBaseTheme is the same?

Comment: No. for scrollable AppBaseTheme has parent Theme.AppCompat.Light whereas for other its AppBaseTheme.

Comment: AppBaseTheme has parent AppBaseTheme for the clickable?

Comment: sorry its android:Theme.Light. And if I try changing the parent to Theme.AppCompat.Light,  I am getting error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: Make sure your project depends on the AppCompat library

Comment: Edit your question with your code.

Comment: code for picker implementation or styles ?

Answer (score 0):

Both projects should use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` as base theme.

I suspect (by looking at the comments) that the project where the spinner has +- buttons does not have the `AppCompat` library added. Therefor this project can't use the `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

You should add the `AppCompat` library to the project where the spinner has buttons and than change the parent of the `AppBaseTheme` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.